# Use same ground with 2 wires?

Tags: pins

So I have 3 ground pins, but I need 4 motors on my Arduino. Can I connect multiple motors to the same ground pin?

Comment: Arduino cannot power a motor directly

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as long as the current isn't excessive. I don't think there are any specs available, but the connector and the width / thickness of the copper tracks on the PCB will be the limiting factor.

Answer (score 2):

All ground is internal connected.
But anyway, you CANNOT use the Arduino's power to power a motor, you will need an external power source.And again, you will connect the external power source's ground to the Arduino's ground.

Comment: If you power a motor directly from an Arduino, the Arduino's microprocessor (e.g. AtMega328P) will get fried.

Comment: And while using the motors, make sure that  the motor does not touch the Arduino board

Comment: How do I control the motor then? I need to control the speed of the motor. How would I do this?

Comment: [link](http://www.homofaciens.de/technics-computer-io-boards_en_navion.htm) for more info on how to do that.

Comment: If you are having problem in coding, comment here and I will give you some sample codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect multiple components to a single ground pin.  IF you are using a breadboard, be sure to put the wire going to the go